# Определить среднюю длину слова во введённой текстовой строке

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Задача - определить среднюю длину слова во введённой текстовой строке.
Учесть, что символы пунктуации на длину слов влиять не должны. Получилось вот так:

```
  class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Go ob = new Go();
        ob.MiddleString();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
class Go
{
    public void MiddleString()
    {
        int allWordLength = 0;
        int wordLength = 0;
        int indBegin = 0;
        int indLast = 0;
        string str1 = "написать прогамму, которая";
        var mas = str1.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.Length; i++)
        {
            indBegin = Array.IndexOf(mas, mas[i]);            //здесь отладчик просто принимает значение indBegin
            indLast = Array.LastIndexOf(mas, mas[i]);         // здесь отладчик просто принимает значение indLast
            wordLength = indLast - indBegin;
            allWordLength = allWordLength + wordLength;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(allWordLength / mas.Length);
    }
}
```

Метод MiddleString по задумке должен содержать два цикла. Внешний проходит по всему массиву(нашей бывшей строке), а внутренний - по подстрокам, попутно вычисляя начальные и конечные индексы, складывая их и таким образом, находя среднюю длину слова. Не получается обращаться элементам массива через цикл. Что-то я уже мозг сломал. Кто может, помогите советом.
 
PS: изменил метод MiddleString. Вроде, можно обойтись одним циклом. Конкретно, теперь не получается определить начальный и конечный индексы элементов массива(т.е., подстрок строки str1), и, соответственно, просчитать среднюю длину слов в массиве. indBegin и indLast всегда принимают значение i. ???

Comment: что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Конкретно, теперь не получается определить начальный и конечный индексы элементов массива(т.е., подстрок строки str1), и, соответственно, просчитать среднюю длину слов в массиве. indBegin и indLast всегда принимают значение i.

Comment: @Олег в цикле вас уже есть i-e слово - `mas[i]`. его длина - `mas[i].Lenght`. не нужно еще раз лезть за ним в оригинальную строку.

Comment: Да, намудрил. Уже решил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понимаю, зачем нужны `indBegin` и `indLast`.
Предлагаю сделать так:

```
foreach (string s in mas)
{
    allWordLength += s.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

средняя длина считается гораздо проще

```
// в самом верху файла
using System.Linq;

// в MiddleString
double averageWordLength = mas.Average(word => word.Length);
```

можно обойтись без перечисления знаков препинания - найти слова с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
double averageWordLength = Regex.Matches(str1, @"\w+")
                            .Cast<Match>()
                            .Average(match => match.Length);
```

но это скорее всего не слишком подойдет в данном конкретном случае :)